# TypeError('cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence')

Tags: python, docker

```py
@api.get("/subject")
async def subject_type_list(
    db: get_db = Depends(),
) :

    data = (
        db.query(
            SubjectType.id, 
            SubjectType.name, 
            SubjectType.korean_name,
        ).filter(
            SubjectType.subject_list_id == 1
        ).all()
    )


    return data
```

Error

```py
fastapi                      | Traceback (most recent call last):
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 152, in jsonable_encoder
fastapi                      |     data = dict(obj)
fastapi                      | TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
fastapi                      | 
fastapi                      | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
fastapi                      | 
fastapi                      | Traceback (most recent call last):
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 157, in jsonable_encoder
fastapi                      |     data = vars(obj)
fastapi                      | TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
fastapi                      | 
fastapi                      | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
fastapi                      | 
fastapi                      | Traceback (most recent call last):
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 419, in run_asgi
fastapi                      |     result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
fastapi                      |     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 271, in __call__
fastapi                      |     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 125, in __call__
fastapi                      |     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
fastapi                      |     raise exc
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
fastapi                      |     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 104, in __call__
fastapi                      |     response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)
fastapi                      |   File "/code/./app/main.py", line 81, in log_request
fastapi                      |     res = await call_next(req)
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 80, in call_next
fastapi                      |     raise app_exc
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 69, in coro
fastapi                      |     await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect, send_no_error)
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 84, in __call__
fastapi                      |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
fastapi                      |     raise exc
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
fastapi                      |     await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
fastapi                      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 26, in __call__
fastapi                      |     raise dependency_exception
fastapi                      |   File "/code/./app/db/deps.py", line 9, in get_db
fastapi                      |     yield db

fastapi                      | ValueError: [TypeError('cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence'), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
```

```
#docker-file
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirement/dev.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/dev.txt
RUN mkdir app
COPY app app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
```

```yaml
#docker-compose file
  fastapi:
    container_name: fastapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    command: >
      bash -c "uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000 --reload"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/code/app
    env_file:
      - env/dev.env
```

When I run this code on my local-uvicorn-venv or remote-linux-server, it is working properly. But when I run this code on my *local docker container*, it makes error as above. how can I solve this problem? I tried remove docker and reinstalled it. but it doesn't work. I don't understand why type error occered.

Comment: The error log shows python 3.10 but your docker is 3.8?

Comment: my vscode python intepreter path settiong is set as my venv python ... 
right. docker python is 3.8, but my venv python is 3.10

Comment: So what you are saying are contradictory. The error log from docker shows 3.10, but you just said the error logs are from your docker that is running 3.8

Comment: yes... you're right. I'll check it. I really appreciate it!!